# Sencha Touch 2 app multilanguage

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.2

I am using sencha touch 2.2 for my app. The app should support multilingual and user should be able to switch between the languages. What is the best approach for this requirement? Can any one help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used https://github.com/mitchellsimoens/Ux.locale.Manager

but there some other approaches, take a look at:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?192132-Multilingual-Translations-best-approach
http://blogs.walkingtree.in/2011/11/26/localizing-sencha-touch-application/